How to create a macro in Swift that doesn’t return a value but simply substitutes code for execution?
I want to create a Swift macro that doesn’t return a value to be inserted somewhere; I want a macro that simply substitutes code in its place.
Specifically, I want to avoid constantly repeating the following line every time I capture self in a closure:
guard let self = self else { assertionFailure(); return }
and use something like:
let closure = { [weak self] in
            #weakSelf
            // ... actual code
          }

Ideally, I want to be able to pass a value to the macro that should be returned from the function where it’s inserted, but that’s the next step.
What I did:
I created a Swift macro using Swift Package Manager.
I’ll leave the code below.
Question: Is this macro even possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong?
The actual code:
@freestanding(expression)
public macro weakSelf() = #externalMacro(
    module: "MyMacroMacros",
    type: "SelfGuardMacro"
)

@main
struct MyMacroPlugin: CompilerPlugin {
    let providingMacros: [Macro.Type] = [
        SelfGuardMacro.self,
    ]
}

public struct SelfGuardMacro: ExpressionMacro {
    public static func expansion(
        of node: some SwiftSyntax.FreestandingMacroExpansionSyntax,
        in context: some SwiftSyntaxMacros.MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> ExprSyntax {
        return ExprSyntax(stringLiteral: """
        guard let self = self else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        """)
    }
}

Using:
class MyClass {
    var closure: (() -> Void)!
    
    func function() {
        self.closure = { [weak self] in
            #weakSelf
            self.printString()            
        }
    }
    
    func printString() {
        print("printing")
    }
}

On self.printString() I'm getting error:
Value of optional type 'MyClass?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'printString' of wrapped base type 'MyClass'
like #weakSelf does nothing.

Setting aside the macro question, by virtue of SE-0345, the guard statement can be simplified to guard let self else {…}.

Also unrelated, do you really want assertionFailure pattern? Do you really want the app to crash if self is nil? Usually, we just return, gracefully handling the “I don’t need to run this closure if the async closure is called after self is deallocated.”

Applying a macro to a closure is listed as one of the "future directions" of function body macros, but it is currently not implemented.
A workaround is to create an expression macro that expands to a closure, so that you can do something like:
doWork(completionHandler: #WeakSelfClosure { result in
    // ...
})

This will then expand to
doWork(completionHandler: { [weak self] result in
    guard let self else {
        return
    }
    // ...
})

Here is an example implementation:
// declaration
@freestanding(expression)
public macro WeakSelfClosure<each P>(
    closure: (repeat each P) -> Void
) -> (repeat each P) -> Void = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "WeakSelfClosure")


// implementation
enum WeakSelfClosure: ExpressionMacro {
    static func expansion(of node: some FreestandingMacroExpansionSyntax, in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> ExprSyntax {
        guard var closure = node.trailingClosure else {
            throw SomeError()
        }
        var signature = closure.signature
        let weakSelfCapture = ClosureCaptureSyntax(
            specifier: .init(specifier: "weak"),
            expression: DeclReferenceExprSyntax(baseName: "self")
        )
        if var signature = closure.signature {
            signature.capture = .init(items: .init {
                for capture in signature.capture?.items ?? [] {
                    capture
                }
                weakSelfCapture
            })
            closure.signature = signature
        } else {
            closure.signature = ClosureSignatureSyntax(capture: .init(items: [weakSelfCapture]))
        }
        closure.statements = .init {
            "guard let self else { return }"
            for stmt in closure.statements {
                stmt
            }
        }
        return ExprSyntax(closure)
    }
}

This example only works for closures that return Void. It is easy to extend this to closures that return any type. The macro can take the value that should be retuned as its parameter.
// closure will return nil when self has been deallocated
let closure: () -> Int? = #WeakSelfClosure(nil) { ... }


I managed to connect the macro to the project, but it doesn’t work with the ‘Trailing Closure Syntax,’ where the closure syntax simply follows the function call instead of being passed as an argument. It says, ‘Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ‘;’.’ Apparently, the compiler just doesn’t understand what’s expected of it.
I’m also having issues with Swift 6 concurrency. There’s a case where the compiler sees the closure with the macro as data race unsafe. I’ll need to look into it further.

Overall, thanks. I understand it’s possible, but fully integrating it will require some work and troubleshooting.

@Nikita Correct, you cannot use the trailing closure syntax with this macro. The concurrency issue should exist even without this macro though. It is likely that you are capturing self in a sendable closure but the type of self is not sendable.

Yes, exactly. The closure captures self, which is not sendable. It’s a simple DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter. It’s interesting why the previous code works, but with the macro, it doesn’t. But perhaps that’s a different topic altogether)
